# Is this a valid proof of Riemann's theorem on removable singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis

In my lecture notes the theorem is stated as follows:

Let $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain, $z_0 \in G$ and $f$ holomorphic in $G\setminus\{z_0\}$.

If $(z-z_0)f(z) \to 0$ for $z \to z_0$, then $f$ is holomorphically extendable over $z=z_0$

My proof:

We can expand $f$ to a laurent series around $z_0$. Because of the fact that $(z-z_0)f(z) \to 0$ for $z \to z_0$ we know that our laurent series actually is a power series which is defined in $z_0$ and obviously holomorphic there, so that $f$ can be holomorphically extended over $z_0$

Is this ok?

Comment: You haven't actually explained much. Why does $(z-z_0)f(z)\to 0$ implies that the Laurent series is actually a power series? You're probably thinking something like if there was a term with negative power, such as $\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^k}$ where $k\geq 1$, then that term must diverge to $\infty$, but the trouble is that a-priori, you could have several other negative powers, such as $\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^3}-\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^2}$ etc, and *maybe* it is conceivable that their singularities "cancel each other out". So, your proof has to rule out any such possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I thought and now I am seeing why this is not that easy.

Comment: I thought a bit about it. If the principal part of the laurent series would be finite than I think that my argument would work since the term with highest negative power would diverge no matter what the other terms are. If the principal part has infinite terms than I thought about the following: Take $g(z) = (z-z_0)f(z)$. The laurent series of $g(z)$ is infinite so that it has an essential singularity in $z_0$. The thing is that according to the theorem of casorati-weierstraß it can't be that $lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)$ exists but it does according to our assumption.

Comment: that does make sense, but the only thing I'd be concerned with is that (atleast for the proof I know) the theorem of Weierstrass already invokes Riemann's removable singularity theorem. So, for your logic to be non-circular, you should recheck your proof of Weierstrass' theorem. Anyway Wikipedia already has a proof of Riemann's theorem, so why not just look at that?

Comment: Yeah, for the proof of Weierstrass' theorem my lecturer used the Riemann theorem. Then I will look for the standard proof. Thank you very much.